# Rails: disable knock JWT authentication in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, jwt

Is there an easy way to allow non-xhr requests to a Rails API being protected by [knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) (JWT) to bypass authentication?

I'd like to be able to easily verify/inspect JSON responses to API actions without having to pass a JWT token with the request while in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by skipping the authentication action in the controller like this:

```
class UserController < ApiController

  skip_before_action :authenticate_user, if: Proc.new { Rails.env.development? }

end
```

This should bypass the knock JWT header check and allow unrestricted access to your actions within this controller. You could also add this to your ApiController class and have it work across all your controllers that inherit from the ApiController class.

Depending on the name of your resource the action could be different. For example, if your resource (model) is called Administrator, your action would be called "authenticate_administrator".